Remove leading digit from an uint in without parsing to string and back
I'm having a uint as 3123456, and I want to get 123456 as number (ideally uint), i.e. with the first digit stripped.
I know I could parse it as a string, remove the leading character, and convert it back:
func (id *MyID) Scan(v any) (err error) {
    asBytes, ok := v.([]byte)
    ...
    myDBNumber := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(asBytes) // the field is of type BINARY in the db
    myDBNumberStr := strconv.Itoa(int(myDBNumber))
    myDBNumberWithoutPrefix, err := strconv.Atoi(myDBNumberStr[1:])
    ...
}

Since I'm using this logic in an sql.Scanner to parse IDs, I'm wondering whether there's a way where this parsing back and forward can be avoided, to improve the performance (or at least to compare the performance).

Can you scan it into a string to begin with? A "digit" is really only a thing in a specifically based string representation, so using a string would be appropriate.

@JimB Thank you for the suggestion! Actually, I'm parsing a MySQL field of type binary with binary.LittleEndian, so I don't know how to achieve that. I've updated my question accordingly. I'll do some more research on that approach, though.

Stripping the last digit can be done easily & quickly using arithmetic means; stripping the first digit will involve something analogous to your string conversion, even if it doesn't explicitly use strings.

You cannot because the internal representation of integers on your hardware is likely base-2 (so you can easily chop "the last bit"), and the (base-10) digits you're talking about only spring into existence once you format your number as such—what JimB said. There exist a way to binary-encode numbers in base-10 called BCD, but in order to use it, your MySQL driver should be able to directly provide this representation which is not likely to happen, I admit. And doing this by hand is basically what strconv does anyway.

@ScottHunter Yeah, I figure I could just go with /10 then. Maybe I should rethink the serialization to the database value, but it would be quite a change.

@kostix I see, that makes sense! If either you or JimB provid that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it! I mean, if it's not feasible, then that's the anwer.

«Maybe I should rethink the serialization to the database value, but it would be quite a change.»—you could think of adding a new column which would contain the rep. you require along with the existing one; updating them in sync is also a challenge but may be in your case it won't require changing many clients or could be done by a DB-level trigger (or the server-side software if the clients talk to it rather than directly to the DB).

@kostix I'm doing quite some comparisions/checks on the ids in my queries, and I'm hesitant to make them more complex by the need to compare two columns at once, Also, I want the id of this database to have the same "outer" from (i.e. a plain BINARY column) as in other databases, where the id is a mere uuid: this way I can re-use these complex queries (resp. reuse the logic how I create these queries code-wise). So I think sadly that's not an option.

Mathematically, you can use log base 10 (6.49..), then take the floor of that (6) and then use the rest from a modulo division by 10^6. I'll leave it to you to find and fix the edge cases (negative numbers, numbers less than one, zero, exact powers of ten etc).

You can create a static array of powers of 10 up to the limit of uintmax, and find the closest smaller value in that array, and do an integer mod.

@BurakSerdar This is interesting! I was wondering whether I could "truncate" my number to all zeros except the leading number, and then substract that one, but mod involves less steps - esp. since truncating in that manner is neither straight-forward nor rather performant. Thanks!

You are looking to an alternative to
func stripLeadingAlternate(i uint) uint {
    if i < 10 {
        return 0
    }
    stripped, _ := strconv.ParseUint(strconv.FormatUint(uint64(i), 10)[1:], 10, strconv.IntSize)

    return uint(stripped)
}

may I suggest calculating the largest power of 10 that is smaller than this number and using a division remainder:
func stripLeading(i uint) uint {
    if i < 10 {
        return 0
    }
    v, m := uint64(i), uint64(10)
    for e, c := uint64(100), 2; e <= v && c < 20; c++ {
        m = e
        e *= 10
    }

    return uint(v % m)
}

Test it on the Go Playground:
package main

import (
    "math"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

func Test_stripLeading(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    tests := []uint{0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 123, 999, 1000, 1001, math.MaxUint}
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(strconv.FormatUint(uint64(tt), 10), func(t *testing.T) {
            t.Parallel()
            want := stripLeadingAlternate(tt)
            if got := stripLeading(tt); got != want {
                t.Errorf("stripLeading(%d) = %v, want %v", tt, got, want)
            }
        })
    }
}

This should work with unit having 64 and 32 bits.
I'm not sure using a table would really improve performance, but you can easily try using powers[c] with var powers = []uint64{10, 100, 1_000, ...} instead of e *= 10:
var powers = []uint64{
    10,
    100,
    1_000,
    10_000,
    100_000,
    1_000_000,
    10_000_000,
    100_000_000,
    1_000_000_000,
    10_000_000_000,
    100_000_000_000,
    1_000_000_000_000,
    10_000_000_000_000,
    100_000_000_000_000,
    1_000_000_000_000_000,
    10_000_000_000_000_000,
    100_000_000_000_000_000,
    1_000_000_000_000_000_000,
    10_000_000_000_000_000_000,
}

func stripLeading(i uint) uint {
    if i < 10 {
        return 0
    }
    v, c := uint64(i), 1
    for ; c < len(powers) && powers[c] <= v; c++ {
    }

    return uint(v % powers[c-1])
}

On my machine the table based version is so marginally faster (33.37 ns/op vs 35.41 ns/op) that I would prefer the slower version with multiplication.
var benchmarkValues = []uint{0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 123, 999, 1000, 1001, math.MaxUint}

func Benchmark_stripLeading1(b *testing.B) {
    for range b.N {
        for _, v := range benchmarkValues {
            _ = stripLeading(v)
        }
    }
}

You might want to change the sample numbers to match your use case, but there is no way you would recognize the difference when you are doing SQL calls ;)
The version with string parsing has 185.2 ns/op (40 B/op, 5 allocs/op), so that is probably a win.

Edit
Alternate version using binary search:
func stripLeading(i uint) uint {
    if i < 10 {
        return 0
    }
    v := uint64(i)
    c := sort.Search(len(powers), func(c int) bool { return powers[c] > v })

    return uint(v % powers[c-1])
}

This thing is faster assuming near uniform distribution:
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
)

func Benchmark_stripLeading(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarkValues := make([]uint, b.N)
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(42))
    for i := range benchmarkValues {
        benchmarkValues[i] = uint(r.Uint64())
    }

    b.ResetTimer()

    for _, v := range benchmarkValues {
        _ = stripLeading(v)
    }
}

It is slower in the initial benchmark (89.17 ns/op), though. It also loses with benchmarkValues[i] = uint(r.Intn(1_000_000)).

Edit2 Just for fun:
package main

import (
    "math/rand/v2"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkStripLeading(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarks := []struct {
        name         string
        stripLeading func(uint) uint
    }{
        {"stripLeadingMult", stripLeading1},
        {"stripLeadingTable", stripLeading2},
        {"stripLeadingBinary", stripLeading3},
        {"stripLeadingAlternate", stripLeadingAlternate},
    }
    for _, bm := range benchmarks {
        b.Run(bm.name, func(b *testing.B) {
            benchmarkValues := newBenchmarkValues(b.N)
            b.ResetTimer()

            for _, i := range benchmarkValues {
                _ = bm.stripLeading(i)
            }
        })
    }
}

func newBenchmarkValues(n int) []uint {
    r := rand.New(rand.NewPCG(42, 24))
    benchmarkValues := make([]uint, n)
    for i := range benchmarkValues {
        benchmarkValues[i] = r.UintN(1_000_000_000)
    }

    return benchmarkValues
}

is a table driven benchmark, with stripLeadingMult being the first, multiplication based solution, stripLeadingTable the second, table base and stripLeadingBinary table based with binary search. It uses evenly distributed 9-digit numbers (r.UintN(1_000_000_000)).
On my machine it results in:
BenchmarkStripLeading/stripLeadingMult-10           225536900            5.380 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkStripLeading/stripLeadingTable-10          203127973            5.898 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkStripLeading/stripLeadingBinary-10         128632011            9.514 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkStripLeading/stripLeadingAlternate-10      33422265            35.03 ns/op       15 B/op          1 allocs/op

This could be improved by sorting the table with the most probably choices in front, but as mentioned: I do not believe it's worth the effort, the first (multiplication based) approach should be fast enough for the problem.
While we can learn a lot here, I think effort optimizing is better spend elsewhere.

It is a sorted slice so you can do a binary search

@BurakSerdar True, but I don't expect uniform distribution of numbers - maybe number > 1.000.000 happen rarely, when at all. Maybe small numbers are much more common than big ones. You can't say without having a sample of the used values, and I think it's not worth the gain.

For what it's worth, in my use case I expect the number to be close to the middle, e.g. to have ~9 digits. But I think many other scenarios won't exhaust the full (and somewhat arbitrary) range of possible values. But again, thanks for all the detailed work here!

@NotX I've added a table driven benchmark for 9 digit numbers. I think what we can all learn here is that you can get easily lost in optimizing something simple, because you can.

Fair enough! It's tempting to get lost in pointless or even flawed optimization after getting started. I also favor the first version - it's slick, it's compact, and gets the job done!
